# How to set default value to Many2one field in odoo10?

Tags: python, odoo-10

I created a many2one field that has relationship custom model. I want to know how to self default value. My default value is "Head/Branch".

Here is my code. Thank You.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
import logging  
class CrmnNewTask(models.Model):   
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

     head_branch=fields.Many2one('head.branch', string='Head/Branch',index=True, ondelete='cascade')

class Headbranch(models.Model):
    _name='head.branch'

    name=fields.Char('Head/Branch')
```

Answer (score 2):

- Please implement this example in your code :

  user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users','User', default=lambda self: self.env.user)
- Here I have set current user name in many2one field. You can also set default value using function. This one another example :

*

```
tax_group_id = fields.Many2one('account.tax.group', string="Tax Group", default=_default_tax_group, required=True)

@api.model
def _default_tax_group(self):
    return self.env['account.tax.group'].search([], limit=1)
```

*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to your form where is field **head_branch**
2. Active developer mode
3. Populate field and save as default https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHPS3.jpg